# Partitioning a List of Vectors into pairs of subsequent Vectors

Tags: r

If I have a list like:

```
ll <- list(c(1,2),c(2,3),c(3,4),c(4,5))
```

How can I split it in:

```
list(list(c(1,2),c(2,3)),list(c(2,3),c(3,4)),list(c(3,4),c(4,5)))
```

In [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), I have the function [Partition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html), where I can do:

```
Partition[ll, 2]
```

but I didn't find a equivalent in `R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `Map`

```
r2 <- Map(list, ll[-length(ll)], ll[-1])
r1 <- list(list(c(1,2),c(2,3)),list(c(2,3),c(3,4)),list(c(3,4),c(4,5)))
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option, using `lapply`:

```
lapply(seq(ll[-1]), function(x) list(ll[-length(ll)][[x]], ll[-1][[x]]))
```

*it also gives identical output:*

```
identical(lapply(seq(ll[-1]), function(x) list(ll[-length(ll)][[x]], ll[-1][[x]])),
          list(list(c(1,2),c(2,3)),list(c(2,3),c(3,4)),list(c(3,4),c(4,5))))
#[1] TRUE
```