# Matlab: How to enumerate the possible ways of forming pairs from a list

Tags: matlab, enumeration

Suppose I have a list of length `2k`, say `{1,2,...,2k}`.  The number of possible ways of grouping the `2k` numbers into `k` (unordered) pairs is `n(k) = 1*3* ... *(2k-1)`.  So for `k=2`, we have the following three different ways of forming 2 pairs

```
(1 2)(3 4)

(1 3)(2 4)

(1 4)(2 3)
```

How can I use Matlab to create the above list, i.e., create a matrix of `n(k)*(2k)` such that each row contains a different way of grouping the list of `2k` numbers into `k` pairs.

Comment: This question has been asked many times in different languages. Python examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45704859/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10568081/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5360220/), R examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30998216/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47213670/). Perhaps looking at those approaches will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear
k = 3;
set = 1: 2*k;
p = perms(set); % get all possible permutations
% sort each two column
[~, col] = size(p);
for i = 1: 2: col
    p(:, i:i+1) = sort(p(:,i:i+1), 2);
end
p = unique(p, 'rows'); % remove the same row
% sort each row
[row, col] = size(p);
for i = 1: row
    temp = reshape(p(i,:), 2, col/2)';
    temp = sortrows(temp, 1);
    p(i,:) = reshape(temp', 1, col);
end
pairs = unique(p, 'rows'); % remove the same row

pairs =
    
         1     2     3     4     5     6
         1     2     3     5     4     6
         1     2     3     6     4     5
         1     3     2     4     5     6
         1     3     2     5     4     6
         1     3     2     6     4     5
         1     4     2     3     5     6
         1     4     2     5     3     6
         1     4     2     6     3     5
         1     5     2     3     4     6
         1     5     2     4     3     6
         1     5     2     6     3     4
         1     6     2     3     4     5
         1     6     2     4     3     5
         1     6     2     5     3     4
```

As someone think my former answer is not useful, i post this.

Comment: Why have you added a new answer rather than editing the existing answer? Since the other answer was not working, as noted by the OP, it should probably be deleted in light of you posting a new answer

Comment: Someone think the existing one is not useful, i don't want to have my new answer misunderstood. Plus, i think the former can inspires others.

Comment: This is a Question and Answer site, if your answer is not correct then it is redundant. People reading this page will be doing so because of this specific question, not looking for inspiration

Comment: This works, but only for small k.  If I want to do k=7, then I will run out of memory.  Ideally, one would like to directly generate the pairs instead of generating all the permutations of (1,...,2k) and eliminate the redundant ones.

Comment: @Raymond Kan Exactly, when k = 10, the matrix will be 654729075x10 (48.8GB). Surely i can write a new function based on the source code of `perms`  or `nchoosek` to directly generate the pairs, but the funcition will only run for k <10. Please tell us what k do you want, and then we can choose a better way to solve.

Comment: @Wolfie That's your viewpoint of stack overflow, not mine. You're chasing answers, but I think the process of thinking is more important.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following brute force way of enumerating the pairs.  Not particularly efficient.  It can also cause memory problem when k>9.  In that case, I can just enumerate but not create Z and store the result in it.

```
function Z = pair2(k)
   count = [2*k-1:-2:3];
   tcount = prod(count);
   Z = zeros(tcount,2*k);
   x = [ones(1,k-2) 0];
   z = zeros(1,2*k);
   for i=1:tcount
       for j=k-1:-1:1
           if x(j)<count(j)
              x(j) = x(j)+1;
              break
            end
            x(j) = 1;
       end
       y = [1:2*k];
       for j=1:k-1
           z(2*j-1) = y(1);
           z(2*j) = y(x(j)+1);
           y([1 x(j)+1]) = [];
       end
       z(2*k-1:2*k) = y;
       Z(i,:) = z;
   end
```

Comment: The number of different partitions is `(2n)!/(2^n * n!)`, which will very quickly grow with `n` - you likely need to limit the scope of what you're trying to do once you have this list if you need `n>9`!

Comment: I agree, I should not store the partition, I can just enumerate each possibility in the loop and do the necessary work for that partition, then move on to the next one.  This way, I can do larger k, say k=12.

Comment: That will help with the memory constraint, but you will soon hit a time constraint iterating over than large of a loop!

Answer (score -1):

```
k = 3;
set = 1: 2*k;
combos = combntns(set, k);
[len, ~] = size(combos);
pairs = [combos(1:len/2,:) flip(combos(len/2+1:end,:))];

pairs =
         
         1     2     3     4     5     6
         1     2     4     3     5     6
         1     2     5     3     4     6
         1     2     6     3     4     5
         1     3     4     2     5     6
         1     3     5     2     4     6
         1     3     6     2     4     5
         1     4     5     2     3     6
         1     4     6     2     3     5
         1     5     6     2     3     4
```

You can also use `nchoosek` instead of `combntns`. See more at [combntns](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/combntns.html) or [nchoosek](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not generating what I need.  There are altogether 1x3x5 = 15 different ways of grouping {1,2...,6} into 3 pairs.  For example, I also should have [1 6 2 3 4 5]

Comment: Sorry for that I misunderstood your question. But it seems that you can use `nchoosek' to write a function yourself to solve this problem. I think in Stack Overflow we need inspire each other and improve ourselves, but do not indulge in a request. At least you should post your code and prove your attempt.